# Weird behaviour on OS X, colour wheel of death, impossible CPU time?

Tags: mac, unix, safari

My computer has been experience some weird issues.  Doing almost any simple operation in a significant application like Sarafi results in the appearance of the colour wheel of death.  Most of the time (When not running Flash), it sits there for a bit then goes away.  Sometimes it's seconds, sometimes longer.

Doing a bit of probing, this kind of thing seems to be happening quite a bit:

user  24289   3.7 11.9   632120 249120   ??  S     2:49PM  12:15.50 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_2146828

I've been reading ps outputs for awhile on other UNIXes, but doesn't this say that a process started 7ish hours ago has used 12.25 hours of CPU time?

I know the machine is dual-core, but seriously?  There have been a couple of times when this was worse, and it showed a total CPU time that was more than 2x the time difference between the current time and the start time, and earlier it was for Adium, not Safari.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, that's tough especially when we pay those prices...

Honestly, I don't want to sound Windowish on this one but before going to deep I would do two things.

1 - Do a hardware check with the leopard DVD and run everything you can.

2 - If you can't see or find problems, do a full reinstall.

This exact situation happened to me a couple of times and I admit that reinstalling one in a while makes a big difference.

Keep us up do date!